# How to change lookup field in Model.viewset to other unique parameter in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using *Modelviewset* in a django-rest-framework project. I want to change the `lookup` field to *`email`(unique)* instead of using `id`.

So I tried adding `lookup_field = 'email'` inside my Schema Viewset but it is not working, and this is what I'm getting:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

How do I resolve this?

**views.py**

```py
class SchemaViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = models.Schema.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchemaSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
```

**models.py**

```py
class Schema(models.Model):
    """Database model for Schema """

    name= models.TextField()
    version = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class SchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes Schema"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.Schema
        fields = (  'id', 'name', 'version', 'email')
```

[image]

[image]

The below image shows what I want but with `email` and not using `id`:

[image]

Comment: All seems fine to me, have you tried just inheriting viewsets.ModelViewSet instead of mixins? Maybe that's the case?

Comment: Yes, i have tried it. It is also not working. Anyway viewsets.ModelViewSet and mixins are similar just i dont want put ,patch and delete, that why mixins are used

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update your code as follow:

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializes Schema"""

class Meta:
    model = models.Schema
    fields = ("id", "email")
    lookup_field = "email"


class SchemaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Schema.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchemaSerializer
    lookup_field = "email"
    lookup_value_regex = "[^/]+"
```

Comment: Still  {"detail":"Not found."}

Comment: @yatharthmeena I've updated answer, it's working for me. It should work for you too

Comment: I have added the images in my question. I am still getting the same response after updating the code with  your answer

Comment: @yatharthmeena my bad, i was checking that on string field, email contains a `.` in it which was not being parsed by defualt regex casuing route matching to fail. Please try this

Comment: this regex will pass everything. you can check here https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

For me I only needed to update the `ViewSet`. No need to update the `Serializer`

```
class SchemaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Schema.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchemaSerializer
    lookup_field = "email"
```

Comment: this is the one I found is working with minimal changes

Answer (score 0):

For me it is even working, when I am not setting the `lookup_field` in the *`Meta`* class of the *serializer*.

So try out only setting the `lookup_field` in your viewset. That might be enough.